# Recursive __iter__ method implementation with generators

Tags: python, iterator, binary-search-tree, yield

I am studying the following [binary-search-tree](/questions/tagged/binary-search-tree) implementation<sup>**1**</sup> in [python](/questions/tagged/python):

```py
class TreeNode():
    def __init__(self, key, val,
                       lc = None, rc = None, parent = None):
        self.key = key
        self.val = val
        self.leftChild = lc
        self.rightChild = rc
        self.parent = parent

    def hasLeftChild(self):
        return not self.leftChild is None

    def hasRightChild(self):
        return not self.rightChild is None

    # in-order iterator
    def __iter__(self):
        if self:
            if self.hasLeftChild():
                for elem in self.leftChild:
                    yield elem

            yield self.key

            if self.hasRightChild():
                for elem in self.rightChild:
                    yield elem                    


class BinarySearchTree():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.size = 0

    def length(self):
        return self.size

    def __len__(self):
        return self.size

    def put(self, key, val):
        if not self.root:
            self.root = TreeNode(key, val)
        else:
            self._put(key, val, self.root)

    def _put(self, key, val, currentNode):
        if currentNode.key >= key:
            if currentNode.hasLeftChild():
                self._put(key, val, currentNode.leftChild)
            else:
                currentNode.leftChild = TreeNode(key, val, parent = currentNode)
        else:
            if currentNode.hasRightChild():
                self._put(key, val, currentNode.rightChild)
            else:
                currentNode.rightChild = TreeNode(key, val, parent = currentNode)
```

Let's consider this example caller code:

```py
from random import randint

bst = BinarySearchTree()

keys = [5, 30, 2, 40, 25, 4]

for key in keys:
    bst.put(key, randint(1000, 2000))

# in-order iteration      
for key in bst.root:
    print(key)
```

producing the expected output:

```
2  
4  
5  
25 
30 
40
```

What is happening behind the scenes when the `for` loop used for the in-order iteration in the caller code is executed?

I know that the `__iter__` method of the `TreeNode` class recursively calls itself in the two `for` loops for the left and right sub-trees.
What I don't manage to grasp is the effect of `yield elem` in those  `for` loops:

> ```
>           if self.hasLeftChild():
>               for elem in self.leftChild:
>                   yield elem
> ```

and

> ```
>           if self.hasRightChild():
>               for elem in self.rightChild:
>                   yield elem
> ```

with respect to the effect of `yield self.key`, which apparently concerns the usual implementation of the [iterator](/questions/tagged/iterator)  protocol as explained in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#generator-types).

More specifically, what is the content of the `elem` variable that is returned by `yield elem` in the above-mentioned nested `for` loops, as opposed to the content of `self.key` (which is the actual key data in the `TreeNode` object) returned by `yield self.key`?

---

1. This is an excerpt from the implementation given in [Problem Solving with Algorithms and Data Structures using Python](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/index.html) by Brad Miller and David Ranum.

Comment: Do you need help understanding the `yield` keyword as a whole or just in this context?

Comment: @ikkuh Just in this context and possibly in similar ones where recursion is also involved.

Comment: @pycoder I read and I am presently re-reading that post, but I still don't manage to come up with a clear picture in this context.